# For which values of $t$ is the subset of $\mathbb{C^2}$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is given below:

> [image]

**My first guess is:**

1-for $t = (2n + 1)\pi$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. we always have $\cos(t) = -1$ and $\sin(t) = 0$ so we will get the vectors $(-1, 1)^{t}$ and $(1, -1)^{t}$ which are linearly dependent.

2- for $ t = 2n\pi$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. the two vectors will become the same vector $(1, 1)^t$ and hence are linearly dependent.

But what about the rationals and irrationals and the other values of $t$ in the integers ?

So I started to row reduce the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(t) + i\sin(t)&1\\
1&\cos(t) - i\sin(t)\\
\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

But I am stucked now, could anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By invertible matrix theorem, the vectors are linearly dependent iff the determinant of the matrix you gave is 0. That is, $$(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))(\cos(t)-i\sin(t))-(1)(1)=0$$ or equivalently $$\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$$
It is known that this identity holds for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so you are saying is that this subset is linearly independent for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ correct?   .... what about if I want to row reduce the given matrix?

Comment: I'm saying they're linearly DEPendent. To row reduce the given matrix, it might be easier to let $a=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ and $b=\cos(t)-i\sin(t)$ and remember that $ab=1$.

Comment: but the matrix I want to reduce does not contain $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Smart $a$ and $b$ are abbreviations in order to get the notation simple. Your matrix is $$ \begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \\ 1 & b \end{pmatrix},$$ now row reduce it.

Comment: but what about the case if $t = \pi/2$ ... we will get the two vectors (i , 1)^t and (1, -i)^t ... where t in the power of the vectors means transpose .... those 2 vectors are linearly independent because there is no values that you can multiply with in the reals to make them linearly dependent ..... so $t =\pi/2 $ does not work

Comment: @Smart Why do you need a value in the reals? $$-i\begin{bmatrix}i\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Because I am checking linear dependence and I need the coefficients to be nonzero for at least one coefficient ..... are you saying that $i $ is nonzero as $i = (1,0)$ ?

Comment: Um yes, $i$ is nonzero. Any (complex) number other than 0 is nonzero by definition.

Comment: So you are saying that even at $t = \pi/2 $ the given subset is also linearly dependent?

Comment: @Smart Yes I am.

Comment: And the coefficients in that case are 1 and $-i$?

Comment: Thank you very much! ..... that was so much helpful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98554/discussion-between-max-zhu-and-smart).